# syntax error when creating work_on table

Tags: php, sql, compiler-errors, syntax-error

So right now I'm re-doing a lab, and I'm on that step of creating table dbo.WORKS_ON

Here is my command so far:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.WORKS_ON
(
Essn    VARCHAR(9)      
Pno INT         not null,
Hours   Decimal(10,2),

);
```

And here is when I try to execute the query I keep getting this same error that I haven't got before, what did I do wrong?

messages:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near 'Pno'.
```

Since this is a lab that involves many steps, feel free to ask or email if you need my other steps before this! Thank you!

Comment: You are missing a comma on the previous line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing a comma after VARCHAR(9), and remove the extra comma beside Decimal(10,2)

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.WORKS_ON
(
Essn    VARCHAR(9),      
Pno     INT         not null,
Hours   Decimal(10,2)

);
```

Comment: Thank you! I wil accept this! also do you mind email me? since I'm getting started on this lab thing, I'm redoing this, I'm only a beginner. and I might need your help later on when I'm doing the final steps. Please considering help me!

Comment: You can post your questions here anytime @Dan Chang. There's a lot of people here who are better and willing to help you. Just make sure to do your part of TRYING to solve it on your own, feel free to ask and we'll do our best to assist you. Cheers! :)